# how can I configure PyCharm so that running a Python script file is visible for Python Console

Tags: python, pycharm

I am writing Python scripts in Pycharm with IPython installed. So I can use Python Console in Pycharm to type Python commands and check the immediate output of the codes. However, when I run a script file after pressing 'Run' button (Shift+F10), all the variables and functions are not visible to the Python Console. This is, however, the feature of Spyder, another popular Python IDE. So here is my question: how can I configure Pycharm so that running a Python script file is visible for Python Console? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also run the part of your code you want to test/check in the console by selecting it and then right clicking and clicking on "Execute Selection in Console Alt-Shift-E". That's what I use sometimes when the debugger is not helpful. After running the code (you can also just "run" functions or classes) the console knows the functions and you can use the same features that Spyder has. However, be aware that when you change the code you need to run it in the console once to update the console definitions!

Answer (score 0):

You can not. But you can use pdb (which will break code execution where you need it and you will be able to do the same things, as in the Python Console).

And, which is better and more powerful, you can use PyCharm's debugger. It represents all available variables in tree-like structures and is really handy.